# How to sharpen and then thin an image of a handwritten digit in Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

Original Image:

[image: Original Image]

Code:

```
image = skimage.img_as_float(original_image) # datattype of original image is uint8
blurred_image = filters.gaussian_filter(image, 3)    
filter_blurred_image = filters.gaussian_filter(blurred_image,1)
alpha = 30
sharpened = blurred_image + alpha * (blurred_image - filter_blurred_image)
```

original_image array: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2EliTzXsTI3VFJHVVgxTHl6UTg/view?usp=sharing

The above code is giving me a different result than what I expected:
[image]

I want to sharpen it and then "thin" the lines so that I can detect its end points.

Comment: check the intermediate images to find the step that goes wrong.
why not just use a threshold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *thin* the image, there's `skimage.morphology.skeletonize`.

Answer (score 2):

from @evbr:

```
imshow(skimage.morphology.skeletonize(load('image.npy')>128),cm.Greys,interpolation='none')
```

for :

[image: skeleton 9]